# error: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy_s’; did you mean ‘memcpy’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c

I am trying to make a memcpy_s() call. Below is my code snippet where I am observing warning
" error: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy_s’; did you mean ‘memcpy’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static const uint32_t ab[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
void main()
{
  uint32_t u[10];
  memcpy_s((void *)&u[0], sizeof(u), (void *)&ab[0], 10 * sizeof(uint32_t));
  
}
```

Comment: And where is `sizeof ab` ? What is its type ?

Comment: Apparenty `memcpy_s` is not available on your platform. But the function is pretty useless anyway, especially in your case where you ignore the return value. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy. Anyway: just use `memcpy` and forget about `memcpy_s`.

Comment: @wildplasser `static const ab[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`  ;-)

Comment: It does compile with MS VC after fixing the `void*)` syntax error.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, I know that, but the sloppy *defaults to int* plus the paranoid annex-K fixation confuses me. [not to mention `void main()` and the needless `(void*)` casts ]

Comment: I am ok to remove void main () instead willing to make int, will that help me to avoid error ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, You mean i am missing #ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__" inclusion ?

Comment: @Coder no you're missing `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` before `#include <string.h>`. But  even that doesn't help here... Strange. Try it anyway

Comment: @Coder unrelated: it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, In case i use (void)memcpy_s(&u[0], sizeof(u), &ab[0], 10 * sizeof(uint32_t)); to  handle void main(), what do you think , I can avoid my error ? if you think its int main() then I can propose (int)memcpy_s(&u[0], sizeof(u), &uv[0], 10 * sizeof(uint32_t));

Comment: `void main()` is totally unrelated to the `memcpy_s` issue, I don't get your last comment. I'd not waste any more time and just use `memcpy`. Apparently `memcpy_s` is not available on your platform.

Comment: `implicit declaration...` errors/warnings with standard C functions usually means: you have forgotton to include the appropriate header file, or the function is not available on your platform. For you latter is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the IDE/Platform you are using doesn't support the `memcpy_s()` variant of `memcpy`, which IMO is good!
I'd recommend using `memcpy()` instead.

**If you haven't already used it before --**

Looking at the [reference page for `memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

> void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);

It needs the following arguments:

> **dest** - pointer to the object to copy to
> **src** - pointer to the object to copy from
> **n** - number of bytes to copy

So,

```
memcpy((void*)&u[0], (void*)&ab[0], 10*sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Or better,

```
memcpy((void*)&u[0], (void*)&ab[0], COUNT_OF(ab)*sizeof(uint32_t));
//                                  ↑ Note this!
```

with a minimalistic, not-so-perfect macro to get count of elements in the array:

```
#define COUNT_OF(var)   (sizeof(var)/sizeof(var[0]))
```

---

By the way, there is a typo in your code:

```
memcpy_s(void *)&u[0], sizeof(u), (void*)&ab[0], 10*sizeof(uint32_t));
//      ↑      ↑ ouch!
```

is the parenthesis. If you at all migrate to a platform where you have `memcpy_s()` supported then change it to:

```
memcpy_s((void*)&u[0], sizeof(u), (void*)&ab[0], COUNT_OF(ab)*sizeof(uint32_t));
```

---

Update:

I learnt from OP that the actual *assignment* is to write a function which behaves like `memcpy()`.
Assuming the nature of arguments to remain consistent with what `memcpy()` needs, adding a `return` to indicate if the copy happened successfully, you can of course add more.

A bare-minimum, simple version can be programmed as:

```
int my_memcpy(void *pDest, void *pSrc, size_t sz)
{
    char *src = (char *)pSrc;   // Or use uint8_t instead of char
    char *dest = (char *)pDest; // Or use uint8_t instead of char
    
    // Validate pointers to avoid seg-faults
    if(NULL == pDest || NULL == pSrc) {
        return -1;
    }
        
    // Copy contents
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: uint32_t u0[10];
 uint32_t u1[10];
 uint32_t u2[10];
 uint32_t u3[10];
 (void)memcpy(u0, ab, 10 * sizeof(uint32_t));
 (void)memcpy_s((void *)&u1[0], sizeof(u1), (void *)&ab[0], 10 * sizeof(uint32_t));
 (void)memmove(u2, ab, 10 * sizeof(uint32_t));
 (void)memmove_s((void *)&u3[0], sizeof(u3), (void *)&ab[0], 10 * sizeof(uint32_t));
 
 // result values are same across
 u0 =  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
 u1 =  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
 u2 =  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
 u3 =  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

Comment: obviously several way I tried and I get identical result . With all the  above clarification and I arrived at a point to get rid of error , I have to write memcpy_s built-in function ,since i cannot use memcpy_s directly in my code . Any link or help to get memcpy_s() source code ?

Comment: When you say *"I have to write memcpy_s built-in function ,since i cannot use memcpy_s directly in my code"*, do you mean you want to write your own function which performs the exact operation that a `memcpy()` or a `memcpy_s()` function call does?

Comment: yes. your understanding is right. Re-write built-in function.

Comment: why not just use `sizeof(ab)` instead of `COUNT_OF(ab) * sizeof(uint32_t)`?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Correct, can be used in this particular case. However, when copying *some* of the array indexes, not all using memcpy, it is required to specify *how many* of them to be copied. That way, OP had the code where he/she was using `10*sizeof(uint32_t)`. So, I thought of suggesting `COUNT_OF` usage there.